# Reconnect KafkaProducer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We are about to write an application to send kafka events

- after startup, this application will run for hours/days/weeks
- depending on the load we will send hunderds of events a minute but there also will be periods, where we will send no events for hours

Is it allowed to create a producer while startup and use the same producer all the time?
in other words: is it guaranteed that the kafka producer can reconnect after every exception (i.E. after network or broker problems, once the resources is available again) (**case A**) or are there exceptions where the application has to close the producer an create a new producer (**case B**)?

**case a:**
(shown simplified)

```
while (true) {
    try {           
      ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, key, value);        
      producer.send(record).get(); // producer always can re-establish the connection in case of a prior exception
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**case b:**
(shown simplified)

```
while (true) {
    try {           
      ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, key, value);        
      producer.send(record).get();
    } catch (ExceptionAbc? ex) {
       // application has to re-create the producer in some cases
       producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The producer will refresh its state every `metadata.max.age.ms`, therefore try to establish connection to the broker and not close without exception during the lifetime of the application.

If the producer is closed, then the app itself should probably fatally crash and have a process manager restart the app rather than the app try to only restart the producer client.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. will the kafkaproducer be closed automatically if the connection can't be reestablished? i can't find a hint in kafka documentation about this.

and if so, how can i know, if the producer is closed or not? the kafka producer and the producer interface has no "isClosed" method. in the source code i can see, that a illegalstate exception will be thrown, if the producer is used after the producer was closed, but this exception is not unique.

Comment: Please use the comment button to ask questions about an answer or edit your question to include more detail.  Answers are meant to answer the question, not ask further questions about an existing answer.